# MFMailComposeViewController send button disable

Tags: ios, email, button, send

I present the `MFMailComposeViewController` according API,generally, the interface is normal, but some users of our app complaint the problem that the send button on the top-right is gray(it becomes disable), she can't press the send button,of course I'm sure I have setted releate parameter.

[image]
I don't know how to slove the problem.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I've been having this issue as well.

Comment: Hey dormitory219
have you find this issue's solution?
I got same issue in my app

Answer (score -1):

User needs to configure his mail account in iPhone to use MFMailComposeViewController to send mails from application.